# Is it essential to specify targetOrigin when using window.parent.postMessage() when sending non-sensitive data?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, postmessage

I'm using

```js
window.parent.postMessage(message, '*')
```

to send data that is **not** private/sensitive to external websites (the message is the height an iframe should be, i.e. importantly, it's not user info or anything sensitive like that).

#### My current understanding of the risks

Using `'*'` for `targetOrigin` means *any* site could intercept that `message`.

Since (in my case) the `message` is not sensitive, this does not directly present any security risk, despite not being a best practice.

I'd have to be extremely careful not forget about this and ever send *sensitive* data via the message in the future. So long as I'm careful not to ever do that, this method will technically be completely safe (despite not being best practice).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I will say that more importantly it is the parent window needs to check event.origin. If the parent only processes the event.origin from its trusted source(s) it would not cause security risk.

Comment: @Qiulang ty. Your info confirms my reasoning that the *receiving* site (parent) needs to limit which site(s) it *receives* messages from (and none others). But my uncertainty stems from the other side: the *sending* site. I'm not sure if there's any risk in leaving the `targetOrigin` as `*`. That gives the flexibility to send to any site, which is fine so long as nothing confidential is being sent (since a malicious site could very easily intercept and read it). I can't * think* of any problems with this approach (so long as the data is not confidential). But I'm a total newbie at this.

Comment: I am curious that since you don't send confidential info why you have this concern in the first place ?

Comment: @Qiulang I know how easily/innocently a sql injection vulnerability can arise, so I'm fairly terrified I might open up either my site or the parent site to an issue if I don't use the correct measures. I am inexperienced with javascript so I lack experience with these functions. I guess the simple answer is: fear of the unknown. But I would rather be cautious than make a blunder given how bad it would be.

Comment: Well I can't say your question but maybe I can share some other information. I also use postMessage to communicate with iframe and its parent. Originally I wrote my own postMessage utility code but then I compared with  https://github.com/EkoLabs/iframily and  https://github.com/SpringRoll/Bellhop and I find bellhop is quite good so now I use bellhop.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely new to this, but it appears the understanding outlined in the question above is indeed correct; at least according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32703073/5783745) fantastic question and answer, the key bit being:

> It isn't a risk per se. It just means that **anybody** can embed your content in a frame and read the messages you send over the API

Basically, `*` as targetOrigin means any site can see the data (i.e. `message`) you're sending, so as long as it's not anything sensitive/private/confidential then it's okay.

The reason it's not best practice is because you or another developer could send sensitive information in the future and may not realise that the `targetOrigin` is open to anyone, and hence it could leak confidential data. Hence why it's technically not essential but best practice to lock down `targetOrigin` to only the sites that you intend to allow access to the data being sent.